# .NET MVC Localization (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I am trying to localize the Script Files.

Currently, I am able to localize the HTML Files by using the Resources,

It is like;

BaseController;

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string cultureName = null;

        // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
        if (cultureCookie != null)
            cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
        else
            cultureName = Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ?
                    Request.UserLanguages[0] :  // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages
                    null;
        // Validate culture name
        cultureName = InDoor.CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe

        // Modify current thread's cultures            
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
}
```

Home Controller;

```
public class HomeController : BaseController{
    ...
}
```

Plus some classes.

To localize script, I have to merge the script file into .cshtml file, But I want both cshtml and script files be separetly.

How can I do this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this post:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d9083/globalization-and-localization-in-asp-net-mvc-4/